# Is this a weird foreign character set or an encoding issue?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, utf-8, character

I'm trying to fix a weird character bug and I don't know what's going on. I had an article written by a foreigner and when I received it, there were weird problems with the font rendering correctly. I've narrowed it down to an issue with the character set being used, but I don't know how to convert it to the correct US version or whatnot. Help?

Here's an example:

buѕіnеѕѕ wеbѕіtе

This is obviously the phrase "business website", but when you cmd+f or cntrl+f and type in the phrase, it does not recognize it as this phrase. Has anyone experienced this issue? The only workaround I've found is to retype the phrase, but this isn't feasible for a 1500 word article.  I've tried copying and pasting it into a text editor to potentially re-encode it, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and remove it from the question.

Comment: But of course I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input from other answers, I was able to single out the offending characters using the following javascript code:

```
// get everything in the div
let article = document.getElementById('post')
let text = article.innerText

// get chars with values outside the ASCII range
let characters = text.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0) > 128 ? c : null)

// filter out null values
let filtered = characters.filter(c => c)

// get the unique values
filtered = Array.from(new Set(filtered))
```

This got me down to the 12 characters that I used Find & Replace to convert them. Not too bad after all that.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the text from this page, and put it into this JavaScript:

`'buѕіnеѕѕ wеbѕіtе'.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))`

The output is:

`["62", "75", "455", "456", "6e", "435", "455", "455", "20", "77", "435", "62", "455", "456", "74", "435"]`

Some of this is in the ASCII range, but a lot of it is look-alike characters from the Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: That would explain why retyping it fixes it, but do you have any idea on how I could fix this without manually retyping everything?

Comment: Other than writing a special-purpose transform in code, or doing a global search-and-replace on the look-alike characters in a text editor, there's no easy way out like specifying a particular character encoding.

Comment: Well, this is helpful.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Maybe I can find something that'll do the heavy lifting for me.